# AngualrJS Fullcalendar: open a modal window upon click on cell in month/week/day view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using arshaw full-calendar wrapped with the angularjs but I am unable to open a modal window when I click on any cell in month view. I was able to do it with Jquery but with angular it is throwing an error saying that the function is undefined when I click on the cell. ( INSIDE the fullcalendar.js file I have edited the div to use the modalwindow upon click). I have included the calendar.js controller in my code and in my controller I can override the header like height buttons in header like prev, next , month, week ,day. But when I define a function and try to call it inside this calendar div i.e

How to do open a modal window with url upon click of cell in month view.

```
    $scope.modalWindow = function() {
    console.log($scope.$$childTail.calObj);
     }



    $scope.uiConfig = {
              calendar:{
                height: 450,
                editable: true,
                header:{
                  left: 'prev,next',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month agendaWeek agendaDay'
                },
                eventClick: function(){
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        $scope.modalWindow ()
                    });

                },
                eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
                eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
                viewRender: $scope.renderView
              }
            };
```

Comment: could you prepare a plunker?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mail2urajendar/j8o2s7ox/4/ here is the fiddle , (open it with firefox) @rnrneverdies